# Downcase a liquid object

Tags: jekyll, liquid

i want to **downcase**  `Liquid-object` in `Jekyll`:

```
<a href="/tags/{{ page.tags }}/">{{ page.tags | downcase }}</a>
```

`{{ page.tags | downcase }}` doesn't work. Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print a list of downcased page's tags, you can do :

```
{% comment %}Create an empty array{% endcomment %}
{% assign tagArray = "" | split: "/" %}

{% for tag in page.tags %}
    {% assign tagDowncased = tag | downcase %}
    {% assign tagArray = tagArray | push: tagDowncased %}
{% endfor %}

<p>{{ tagArray | joint: ", " }}</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!